# can't see ng-include's content with ui-router and ui-bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-routing

I have a basic tab example almost working. The main page is a list of items, upon selection, a new tab should open with details of that item.

The problem i have is none of the dynamic content inside the tab's `div` is visible even though I have a controller and route configured properly. I have used UI-Bootstrap's tabs.

In this plunker example the tabs are almost working, however on my computer the entire launcher is shown inside the existing launcher upon clicking an item. I was also getting a warning that I was trying to load angular twice.

`This is my basic tab launcher:`

```
<h2>List of items</h2>

<tabset>
  <tab heading="Main Item">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ITEM Id</th>
          <th>ITEM Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td>
            {{ item.id }}
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="" ng-click="addTab(item.name)">{{item.name}}</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </tab>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading={{tab.name}}>
    <div ng-include src="tab.url">
    </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Full code is at: http://plnkr.co/edit/j4kel2IYrcXWKzVJlNlx?p

I don't know how much of this plunk to include here with this text. Please let me know and i will correct accordingly.

Comment: An ng-include inside a tab does not a route make.  You can put a controller wrapper in the template that you are including. http://plnkr.co/edit/Sdo4O08UzEE9wmCSvcMn?p=preview

Comment: is there a reason for that? the docs don't seem to mention this. i was trying to avoid writing an explicit `ng-controller` and let some central place handle all that

Comment: ngRoute is just not part of the bootstrap-ui tabs.   You can create a nav routing that looks like tabs and routes to pages, or with ui-router you can manage individual page states.

Comment: So you're saying if i use a regular `div` below the table (no tabs) this will work? could you give me examples of these two scenarios?